# Linux Kernel Module , prevent usbcore to registered another interface after probe

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

I am looking for a way to prevent usbcore to register a new interface usbhid or other after a "request" probe .

**C function Linux Kernel Module (mUSBdriver.c)**

```
...
static int mUSBdriver_probe(struct usb_interface *interface, const struct usb_device_id *id){
       printk(KERN_INFO "mUSBdriver: new USB device PLUGGED!");
       return 0; // indicate we will manage this device
       //return -ENODEV;  indicate we will NOT manage this device
    }
...
```

**here are my steps compilation and insertion**

```
rmmod usbhid 
rmmod mUSBdriver 
make 
insmod mUSBdriver.ko
```

**When i Hot-Plug my device**

```
~# tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog
...
...kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver mUSBdriver
...kernel: usb 2-1: Product HID Keyboard
...
...kernel: mUSBdriver:new USB device PLUGGED!
...
```

**My device is an HID keyboard class, then**

```
~# tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog
...
...kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver mUSBdriver
...kernel: usb 2-1: Product HID Keyboard
...
...kernel: mUSBdriver:new USB device PLUGGED!
...kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
...kernel: usbhid: USB HID core driver
...
```

Then nothing appears since I decided to manage (return 0) this device.
I am looking for a solution to prevent usbcore registered another interface after my driver receive a probe. I want to consider this device as "BAD USB" and cancel all other operations. I search in usb.h but nothing .

Any idea how do I take ?

```
my idea: 
- send a notification to usbcore ?
- hook on usbcore  ?

(but I do not know how to do it)
```

Comment: And one comment, don't call your stuff musb since there is already USB/UDC driver with such name. It brings more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`usbcore` never allows two drivers to attach to the same interface at the same time.

What `usbcore` actually did was to register a new interface **driver**. This has nothing to do with whether an interface for that driver exists, or is actually available; it happens when that driver (module) is being loaded.

---

However, there might be a problem: the first driver that gets probed, wins. If the `usbhid` driver is already loaded, it's possible that it attaches before your own driver.

To prevent `usbhid` from attaching to your device, you have to tell it to ignore that device with a module option:

```
options usbhid quirks=0x1234:0x5678:4
```

or add a `HID_QUIRK_IGNORE` entry to `drivers/hid/usbhid/hid-quirks.c`.